# How to set kivy widget id from Python code file

Tags: python, widget, kivy

I need help assigning ids to new kivy widgets that are created from a python function

I've tried :

```
old = Label(id = 'old')
```

and :

```
old = Label()
old.id = 'old'
```

but it doesn't seem to work because, whenever i try referencing the widgets, it gives me an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ways that you have creating `id` in Python code are correct.

But you cannot reference them using `self.ids.old` or `self.ids['old']` because they don't exist in `self.ids`. The `self.ids` dictionary type property contains only all widgets tagged with ids defined inside kv file.

To reference `id` defined in Python code, in this example use `self.old`.

[Accessing Widgets defined inside Kv lang in your python code](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code)

> When your kv file is parsed, kivy collects all the widgets tagged with
>   id’s and places them in this `self.ids` dictionary type property. That
>   means you can also iterate over these widgets and access them
>   dictionary style.

Answer (score 5):

@ikolim is correct, but there is a very ugly and not recommended way to accomplish what you want:

```
import weakref

old = Label()
self.ids.add_widget(old)
self.ids['old'] = weakref.ref(old)
```

This actually adds the `old` id to the dictionary (assuming `self` is the correct  container). A better way would be to just keep a reference to the `old` `Label`.

Answer (score 1):

For widgets that are made on the python side dynamically, they will not be found in `self.ids`. Instead, you have to iterate through `self.children` to find the id assigned to the widget. For example:

```
for child in self.children:
    if child.id == 'old':
        print child.text
        print 'Text found.'
        break
```