# How can I reset ToggleButton state before entering the screen?

Tags: python, kivy, togglebutton

I got lots of ToggleButton in screenB and I wand to reset all of them before entering the screen.

```
class screenB(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MorePage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.AddWidget)

    def AddWidget(self, *args):
        for i in range(len(all_brand)):
            brand_name = all_brand[i]
            if brand_name[0] == "A" or brand_name[0] == "a":
                self.tbutton = MyToggle(id=brand_name, text=brand_name)
                self.ids.Axxx.add_widget(self.tbutton)
                print(self.tbutton.id)
            elif brand_name[0] == "B" or brand_name[0] == "b":
                self.tbutton = MyToggle(id=brand_name, text=brand_name)
                self.ids.Bxxx.add_widget(self.tbutton)
            elif brand_name[0] == "C" or brand_name[0] == "c":
                self.tbutton = MyToggle(id=brand_name, text=brand_name)
                self.ids.Cxxx.add_widget(self.tbutton)
            ....

    def reset_state(self):
        print(self.ids)
        print(self.ids.Axxx.ids)
        for i in all_brand:    # all brand includes all ids of ToggleButton added in AddWidget
            self.ids[i].state = "normal"
```

in .kv file,

```
<screenB>:
    on_pre_enter:
        root.reset_state()
    Label:
        id: aaa
    Label: 
        id:bbb
    StackLayout:
        id: Axxx
    StackLayout:
        id: Bxxx
    StackLayout:
        id: Cxxx
    ...
```

I tried to call `reset_state` before entering screenB. Then I found that `self.ids` gave me only aaa, bbb, Axxx, Bxxx, Cxxx but nothing added in `AddWidget`. And `self.ids.Axxx.ids`gave me empty dict. But if I print tbutton.id immediately after the ToggleButton is added, I get the current return.

How can I reset state of all ToggleButton then? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Does this code even work?, your `Clock.schedule` call is missing a parameter

Comment: It works as I expected. I think you are talking about time parameter. From Kivy website [https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html], `Clock.schedule` without that means call the function as soon as possible.

Comment: Which one is the main screen, ScreenB?

Comment: No. Main screen is not included here. A button in main screen connects to ScreenB.

Comment: Try to delay the call to `AddWidget`..basically change `Clock.schedule_once(self.AddWidget)` to `Clock.schedule_once(self.AddWidget, .3)`

Comment: It is just the same as before...

Comment: I found this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/52151913/12815472] and I think this may be the hint of my problem but I still cannot solve it. For example, id of tbutton is abc and I typed `self.abc.state = "normal"` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see now, `self.Axxx.ids` doesnt return anything because you dont have any children with `id`s in that widget, simply do this instead

```
for child in self.ids.Axxx.children:
    child.state = "normal"
```

That should do it